# How can I make this not happen in the right and left corners?

Tags: flutter

How can I make this not happen in the right and left corners?
I am radiusing the corners with fromLTRBAndCorners. However, it breaks down while browsing the menu.

[image]

```
..lineTo(size.width, 0)
  ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
  ..lineTo(0, size.height)
  ..addRect(Rect.fromPoints(const Offset(0, 100), Offset(size.width, 0)))
  ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
    0,
    0,
    size.width.toDouble(),
    size.height.toDouble(),
    topLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
    topRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
    bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
    bottomRight: Radius.zero,
  ))
  ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
  ..close();
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone to help fix this issue. I'd suggest you add more information. 

- What are you using to draw this
- Does it work at any point
- When does it break
- What have you tried to fix it

Comment: I have shared all the code below.

Comment: Still doesn't help much. There's no context, we don't know what's happening, why it's happening, what are you expecting, what is it doing instead, when is it doing it etc. Just trying to make sure you get an answer, but with a question in the way you wrote no one will answer this. There's nothing to go off.

Answer (score 0):

all code

```
late double loc;
  late double s;
  Color color;
  TextDirection textDirection;

  NavCustomPainter(double startingLoc, int itemsLength, this.color, this.textDirection) {
    final span = 1.0 / itemsLength;
    s = 0.2;
    double l = startingLoc + (span - s) / 2;
    loc = textDirection == TextDirection.rtl ? 0.8 - l : l;
  }

       @override
          void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
            final paint = Paint()
              ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 192, 241)
              ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
              ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, convertRadiusToSigma(5));
        
            final path = Path()
              ..moveTo(0, 0)
              ..lineTo((loc - 0.1) * size.width, 0)
              ..cubicTo(
                (loc + s * 0.20) * size.width,
                size.height * 0.05,
                loc * size.width,
                size.height * 0.60,
                (loc + s * 0.50) * size.width,
                size.height * 0.60,
              )
              ..cubicTo(
                (loc + s) * size.width,
                size.height * 0.60,
                (loc + s - s * 0.20) * size.width,
                size.height * 0.05,
                (loc + s + 0.1) * size.width,
                0,
              )
              ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
              ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
              ..lineTo(0, size.height)
              ..addRect(Rect.fromPoints(const Offset(0, 100), Offset(size.width, 0)))
              ..addRRect(RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
                0,
                0,
                size.width.toDouble(),
                size.height.toDouble(),
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                bottomRight: Radius.zero,
              ))
              ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
              ..close();
              canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
          }
```

Comment: I updated the code.